# Send custom values with jquery UI autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I decided to use jquery-ui Autocomplete Combobox, but until now I didn't noticed that it doesn't sends values that you have edited. If you select value from dropdown list, edit it and send form it will send original value, before you edited it. I want to allow visitors to edit values in dropdown list and send them with form as they want it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Combobox, we cannot edit the values in the list we can only select from the existing list.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You could create a ajax powered combobox from scratch. That could give suggestions, which an user can choose from existing option or create his own value.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you want is implemented in UFD: the Unobtrusive Fast-filter Dropdown

From the features wiki:
"Optional submission of free text: copy the master 'name' attribute to the text input, and suffix the master name."

Find it here: http://code.google.com/p/ufd/